# Why do we talk about "Head Transplant" and not "Body Transplant"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

This last years, articles started to talk about the possibility to the

> "surgical operation involving the grafting of one organism's head onto the body of another". <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant)</sub>

I am really surprised of the usage of the word **head** for this kind of transplantation.

Is that a correct word usage? I used to think that we transplant a body part (organ, member...) to a living person, and in that case, the living person is the "head"... so why in that case, is it reverted?

Would I be allowed to talk about a **body** transplant instead?

Comment: I suspect there are 2 cases: (1) where the subjects are treated objectively, the lesser portion is transplanted to the greater; and (2) where one subject is the primary beneficiary, the other entity’s parts are transplanted to the beneficiary.

Comment: 'The body' includes the head.

Comment: @NigelJ wouldn't that be general then?

Comment: @Ustanak I was just thinking out loud, there. My body includes my head. They belong together.

Comment: But in the case of this could really happen one day, the person will rather say "I just received a *body* transplant" than "a *head* transplant"...(?)

Comment: A body is a body, even if you trim off all the appurtenances—including the head.

Comment: @ May I know the reason of the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

"Head transplant" very clearly implies that one organism's head is transplanted onto another's body. "Body transplant" is unclear. It doesn't necessarily imply that the split occurs between the body and the head. The word "body" is generally the term for the whole and without context the term will include the head.

So even if it makes sense that the "recipient" is the head who is receiving a new body, "head transplant" is simply more clear and natural to use.